# Invalid Date Format Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, mobile

When parsing date and time from an API call which is formatted like this `2018 - 04 - 18T21:51:00` I get and error that states

[image]

and I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

```
/// I set in which format should my data be, and parse the data from the API call 
 Text('Date and Time: 
${DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(DateTime.parse(apicall.timeanddate))}'),
```

After that I would format the Date and Time according to Locale language preference of the device.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is that a valid datetime format? Maybe you should get it as string and play with it a little then parse to datetime. Like deleting the - or spaces.

Comment: I think you should delete the spaces. 2018-04-18T21:51:00 should be an ok format.

Comment: I copied your code and tried running it. It worked perfectly fine while I entered `var now = DateTime.now();   DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(now);`

Comment: I think that the problem is `Consumer` of the `Provider`, I will check it again an update the question if needed.

Comment: It stays the same, the error persists, it is not from the `Consumer/Provider`....

Answer (score 0):

The format you are passing is invalid, so you need to transform it:

```
String getDateTime(String dateFromServer){
  dateFromServer = dateFromServer.replaceAll(" ","");
  dateFromServer = dateFromServer.replaceAll("T"," ");
  return dateFromServer;
}
```

I replaced all spaces and T that were causing problems you can now use this with:

```
DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(getDateTime(apicall.timeanddate));
```

Hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: Don't need to delete T's, deleting spaces will be enough.